# How to make fillers in GTK applications smaller?

Tags: linux, gui, gtk

I start an GTK-based IDE on my netbook, and it looks not so nice: too much screen space space wasted on dull gray areas.

[image: Original]

I want it to be more like this:

[image]

How to make GTK programs to economize screen space by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a theme that has narrower elements.

Comment: How to switch or create a theme?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=gtk+theme

Comment: Found "gtk-theme-switch". Now looking how to create a theme with narrower elements.